# Printing the results from fetch() in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to recreate the example used in the docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

```
componentDidMount: function(){
        this.createRow();
    },

createRow : function(){
        var results = fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return responseJson.movies;
            });
        this.setState({
            'xyz' : results,
            'people' : [{'name':'something_else', 'email':'email@gmail.com'}, {'name':'morgan', 'email':'mogo@gmail.com'}]

        });
    },
```

However, when I goto print the results in the `render` method

```
render: function(){
        console.log(this.state.xyz)
```

I am getting:
`undefined` the first time the page renders (and `xyz` hasn't been set, so that makes sense)

`Promise { <state>: "pending" }` the second time when page is rendered (`createRow()` is run from `componentDidMount`)

Why am I getting `pending` state and not the `movies` object like the example shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the case is, when the setState is executed (because your fetch is async, but the flow goes async with fetch method), your promise is not resolved or rejected yet, because the promise is in the pending state. so, you need to call setState after the promise is resolve. can you try this :

```
createRow : function(){
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
               this.setState({
                 'xyz' : responseJson.movies,
                 'people' : [{'name':'something_else', 'email':'email@gmail.com'}, {'name':'morgan', 'email':'mogo@gmail.com'}]

               });
            });
    },
```